# Passing Dicts using Pointers in Python HuggingFace

Tags: python, pointers, huggingface-transformers, huggingface

AFAIK, in Python objects are passed by reference, then why do HuggingFace keeps using pointers to pass objects? Example snippet below taken from the tutorial at this link: https://huggingface.co/learn/nlp-course/chapter3/4?fw=pt

```
raw_inputs = [
    "I've been waiting for a HuggingFace course my whole life.",
    "I hate this so much!",
]
inputs = tokenizer(raw_inputs, padding=True, truncation=True, return_tensors="pt")
print(inputs)

from transformers import AutoModel

checkpoint = "distilbert-base-uncased-finetuned-sst-2-english"
model = AutoModel.from_pretrained(checkpoint)

outputs = model(**batch)  #  <-- What does this even mean? 
print(outputs.loss, outputs.logits.shape)
```

Comment: Corrected URL: https://huggingface.co/learn/nlp-course/chapter2/2?fw=pt  SO not letting me edit url in the original post

Comment: Python does not use the same syntax as C. `**` is dictionary unpacking in Python, not pointer dereferencing. The elements of `batch` become keyword arguments to `model` with that call.

Comment: see: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/packing-and-unpacking-arguments-in-python/

Comment: Python does *not have pointers*, and it never uses call by reference as an evaluation strategy.

Comment: Python and C are two different languages, and `*` has nothing to do with pointers in Python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`func(**kwargs)` is passing dictionary `kwargs` as keyword (non-positional) arguments to `func`.

If `func` is defined as such:

```py
def func(arg1, arg2, arg3):
    pass
```

And dict `kwargs` is such:

```py
kwargs = {
    "arg1": value1,
    "arg2": value2,
    "arg3": value3,
}
```

Then calling `func(**kwargs)` is equivalent to calling `func(arg1=value1, arg2=value2, arg3=value3)`.

It has nothing to do with pointers. Python does not have pointers.

Comment: Yes, while the Python language does not have the notion of pointers outside of its C API, the arguments passed to functions are still done via pointers to `PyObject`s uder the hood. Python *does* use pointers, but they're hidden from view. Python uses pointers extensively, but they're hidden from normal use.